# Getting Postfix Bounce on GCP Google Cloud VM using Sendgrid - sender non-delivery notification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, sendgrid, postfix-mta, email-bounces

I am running Debian 8 on GCP VM. Trying to send e-mails with postfix using Sendgrid SMTP service, but I am getting bounce and none of the e-mails are getting delivered.

I followed documentaion and instructions, but not sure where the issue is ...

I tried using apikey approach as well as username/password, but both didn't work.

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid

Syslog message below

```
May  4 23:30:20 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm systemd[1]: Stopping System Logging Service...
May  4 23:30:20 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
May  4 23:30:20 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
May  4 23:30:31 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm postfix/pickup[4953]: 9F834A0CF7: uid=0 from=<root@elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm.c.elegant-dxl-dream.internal>
May  4 23:30:31 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm postfix/cleanup[4976]: 9F834A0CF7: message-id=<20180504233031.9F834A0CF7@dxlhoa-vm.c.dxl-dream.internal>
May  4 23:30:31 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm postfix/qmgr[4954]: 9F834A0CF7: from=<root@elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm.c.elegant-dxl-dream.internal>, size=428, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  4 23:30:31 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm postfix/error[4978]: 9F834A0CF7: to=<ctg.cloudtechguy@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced ([smtp.sendgrid.net]:2525)
May  4 23:30:31 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm postfix/cleanup[4976]: A1BA6A0D0A: message-id=<20180504233031.A1BA6A0D0A@dxlhoa-vm.c.dxl-dream.internal>
May  4 23:30:31 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm postfix/bounce[4980]: 9F834A0CF7: sender non-delivery notification: A1BA6A0D0A
May  4 23:30:31 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm postfix/qmgr[4954]: 9F834A0CF7: removed
May  4 23:30:31 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm postfix/qmgr[4954]: A1BA6A0D0A: from=<>, size=2434, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  4 23:30:31 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm postfix/error[4978]: A1BA6A0D0A: to=<root@elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm.c.elegant-dxl-dream.internal>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0/0/0/0.02, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced ([smtp.sendgrid.net]:2525)
May  4 23:30:31 elegant-dxlhoa-logintry-vm postfix/qmgr[4954]: A1BA6A0D0A: removed
?Starting                                                                                              289,56        Bot
```

Main.cf configuration below

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = dxlhoa-vm.c.dxl-dream.internal
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = dxlhoa-vm.c.dxl-dream.internal, localhost.c.dxl-dream.internal, , localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:2525
mtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
default_transport = error
relay_transport = error
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
header_size_limit = 4096000
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
bounce_template_file = /etc/postfix/bounce.cf
```

Appreciate if anyone can help,

thanks
TP

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this article](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Troubleshooting/testing_your_connectivity_to_sendgrids_smtp_relay_using_telnet.html) you can run following command to make sure there is connectivity to SendGrid's SMTP relay.

```
telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 2525
```

Also, visit [this documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/postfix.html) for some tips on Postfix configuration for SendGrid on Linux machines.